# Generate random number within a range (0-100k) in a cluster environment

Tags: java, mongodb, random, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I have to generate random number within a range (0-100.000) in a cluster environment (many stateless Java based app servers + Mongodb) - so every user request will get some unique number and will maintain it in the next few requests.

As I understand, I have two options:
1. have some number persisted in mongo and incrementAndGet it - but it's not atomic - bad choice.
2. Use Redis  - it's atomic and support counters.
3. Any idea? Is it safe to use UUID  and set a range for it ?
4. Hazelcast ?

Any other though?

Thanks

Comment: pregenerate the random numbers,store them all, then just sequentially assign each user the "next" number in that array/list/table/whatever?

Comment: If uniqueness is the true requirement and sequential is OK, use the canonical http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/ approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would leverage the existing MongoDB infrastructure and use the MongoDB findAndModify command to do an atomic increment and get operation.

For the shell the command would look like.

```
var result = db.ids.findAndModify( {
                           query: { _id: "counter" },
                           sort: { rating: 1 },
                           new : true,
                           update: { $inc: { counter: 1 } },
                           upsert : true
                         } );
```

The 'new : true' returns the document after the update.  Upsert creates the document if it is missing.

The [10gen supported driver](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#findAndModify%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20boolean,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) and the [Asynchronous Driver](http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/apidocs/?com/allanbank/mongodb/builder/FindAndModify.html) both contain helper methods/builders for the find and modify command.